# Callback with CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, callback

I'm trying to create a really simple callback using some Strings. The IDE's code sense is  is moaning about an unchecked call to exceptionally. Can anyone give me a fix for this? The idea in the end is to wrap a network call so that the promised result is returned and I can tack on additional functions as needed.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class FuturesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new FuturesTest().go();
    }

    private void go() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new MakesANetworkCall())
                .whenComplete(new BiConsumer<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(String result, String s) {
                        System.out.println(result.toString());
                    }
                })
                .exceptionally(new Function<Exception, Exception>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public Exception apply(Exception e) {
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                       return e;
                                   }
                               }
                ).thenApplyAsync(new Function<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String apply(String o) {
                        System.out.println("Last action of all!");
                        return null;
                    }
                });

        System.out.println("Main thread will sleep");
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        System.out.println("Program over");
    }

    class MakesANetworkCall implements Supplier {

        @Override
        public String get() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Ground control to Major Tom");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//            int i = 2/0;
            return new String("Major Tom reporting!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `new CompletableFuture<String>().supplyAsync` to invoke a `static` method? And why don’t you use lambda expressions?

Comment: What do you want the call to `exceptionally()` to do?

Comment: *Edit* changed to static, thanks for pointing that out, Holger.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, your class `MakesANetworkCall` implements the raw type `Supplier` instead of `Supplier<String>`. This will effectively disable the type checking and hide all errors you made, so it’s not the single warning you should worry about, as that’s not the only thing wrong in your code:

- The `BiConsumer` passed to `whenComplete` should be able to consume a `Throwable` as its second argument.
- The `Function` passed to `exceptionally` should consume a `Throwable` and return an alternative result.

Further, you are invoking a `static` method using the expression `new CompletableFuture<String>()` as its target and you have an obsolete string creation expression as `new String("Major Tom reporting!")` where the simple constant `"Major Tom reporting!"` will do. Generally, you seem to try to always use an inappropriate method, i.e. one designed to consume things you don’t use or one for supplying a value where you don’t have one. Consider this:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new MakesANetworkCall())
    .thenAccept(result -> System.out.println(result))
    .exceptionally(e -> { e.printStackTrace(); return null;})
    .thenRun(()->System.out.println("Last action of all!"));
```

This does what seems to be your intention. If you ensure that your `MakesANetworkCall` correctly implements `Supplier<String>`, this should compile without any warnings.

Comment: Thanks. It's my first attempt at even looking at this functionality. I've marked this correct as Holger did get there first, but with a nod to OldCurmudgeon

Answer (score 5):

Your core issue is with `class MakesANetworkCall implements Supplier {`. This is using raw types and therefore hides further problems. Fix that to `class MakesANetworkCall implements Supplier<String> {` and fix all ensuing issues and you get:

```
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new MakesANetworkCall())
            // Not <String, String>
            .whenComplete(new BiConsumer<String, Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(String result, Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println(result);
                }
            })
            // Not <Exception,Exception>
            .exceptionally(new Function<Throwable, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    // Must return a Streing
                    return t.getMessage();
                }
            }
            ).thenApplyAsync(new Function<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(String o) {
                    System.out.println("Last action of all!");
                    return null;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

`CompletableFuture.exceptionally` is declared like so:

```
public CompletableFuture<T> exceptionally(Function<Throwable, ? extends T> fn);
```

You're passing it a `Function<Exception, Exception>`, whereas you should be passing it a `Function<Throwable, String>`.

Comment: Actually, since the supplier as posted in the question implements the raw type `Supplier`, there is no compiler error at all. Otherwise, the `whenComplete(new BiConsumer<String, String>() { … })` will already generate a compiler error, so the type of the subsequently chained call is unknown. The `new CompletableFuture<String>()` used to invoke the `static` method `supplyAsync` has no effect on the type of the `CompletableFuture`…

Comment: I didn't say it was a compiler error- it's a warning in my IDE -- with changes above I get "Unchecked call to exceptionally(Function<Throwable, ? extends T>) as a member of raw type CompletableFuture"