# How to know when the tasks of threadpool is over in java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, future, nonblocking

I am making a news update app. For this it needs to be able to get updates on given periods of times. In this i have created a timer to run the callable plugin on given periods of time. Here i used a FixedThreadPool(executor). 
For this what i want is to know when the future has finished its job so i can call the updateHeadlines method. but when i use finished.get() it blocks the gui. is there a way to know without blocking when the job has been finished to i can update the GUI after that.

```html
for (Callable curplugin : plugin) {
            new Timer(((NewsPlugin) curplugin).getUpdateFrequency(), new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Future<?> finished = executor.submit(curplugin);

                    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {   
                            try {
                                ArrayList<Headline> news = (ArrayList) finished.get();
                                updateHeadlines();
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

Comment: Why not have the `curplugin` action be responsible for making the `invokeLater` call as its last step? (One way to do this is by making a composed Runnable that calls `curplugin.call()` and then takes its results and calls invokeLater. Then take _that_ runnable, and and submit it to the thread pool.)

Comment: Have a look at ExecutorCompletionService: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html

Comment: Can you explain it more. the gui uses the result from curplugin and combine it with some others. so i can call it within curplugin to update the gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no need to combine `Timer` and `ExecutorService`, or to use a callback. Instead, schedule a `Runnable` that invokes the plugin, and schedules an `invokeLater` to display the result:

```
for (NewsPlugin plugin : plugins) {
  Runnable task = () -> {
    List<Headline> news;
    try {
      news = plugin.call(); /* There's really no need for plugin to be `Callable` */
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(this::updateHeadlines);
  };
  int period = plugin.getUpdateFrequency();
  executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, period, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: updateHeadLines is placed inside my MainFrame.java file which is the main Frame GUI and is static. so should i write another runnable inside invoke later and then call the method inside the runnable

Comment: @Yomal Probably not. Doesn't `updateHeadlines` simply display the new headlines, which have already been fetched? That's why it has to be done on the AWT thread, right?

Comment: the `updateHeadlines` will call the getheadlines methods in the plugins which stores the headlines after each update. and it will display all of them together.

Comment: @Yomal Okay, then the code should be fine as I wrote it.

Comment: yes got it working thanks alot this helped me alot :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8. There is a completeable future, In which you can register a callback, which will be called when task is completed. I think that will be helpful to you.

May be this will help you [Callback with CompletableFuture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877380/callback-with-completablefuture)

Comment: How would you use `CompletableFuture` with a task on a recurring schedule?

Answer (score 0):

From Java 8 onward you could use a `CompletableFuture`to get a callback on completion for one shot tasks. Before Java 8 you could use Guava's `ListenableFuture`, which has similar functionality.

For recurrent tasks use an [observable](http://reactivex.io/intro.html) pattern, which is the counterpart to futures for handling multiple items returned from a recurring task. Java does not seem to offer a good OOTB solution here though.

Comment: How would you use `CompletableFuture` with a recurring scheduled task?

Comment: For recurrent tasks use an observable pattern, which is the counterpart to futures for handling multiple items. See http://reactivex.io/intro.html

Comment: If you mean to say that `CompletableFuture` is not applicable to recurrent tasks, and that the observer pattern should be used instead, you should edit your answer.